# Deleting selected row from DataTable bound DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, datagridview

Consider a `DataGridView` whose `DataSource` is a `DataTable`. The dataGridView allows one row to be selected at a time. There is a "delete" button, which should delete the selected rows, by one of the columns, from the bound dataTable.

I have configured the `DataGridView` to be uneditable, from the user's point of view. It should only be possible to delete a row (from the dataTable and the grid) via a separate "delete" `Button` I have created. The event handler for this is shown below:

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
var usersTable = myGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow selected in myGridView.SelectedRows)
            {
                string name = (string)selectedRow.Cells[0].Value;
                foreach (DataRow tableRow in usersTable.Rows)
                {
                    if (tableRow["Name"].ToString().Equals(name))
                        tableRow.Delete();
                }
                usersTable.AcceptChanges();
            }

            myGridView.DataSource = usersTable;
}
```

How to does this properly, without "collection was modified, enumeration might not execute" errors?

The grid is being populated as follows:

```
private DataTable usersTable = new DataTable("Users");

void Populate()
{
    usersTable.Columns.Clear();
    usersTable.Rows.Clear();
    usersTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    // addd other columns...

    foreach (var user in usersCollection)
    {
        usersTable.Rows.Add(user.GetName()),
        // add other rows...
    }

    // bind the data
    myGridView.DataSource = usersTable;
}
```

Comment: The `DataGridView` will allow the user to simply press the `Delete` key to delete the selected row.  No code required.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp will the bound `DataTable` be affected by this, though? That is the important part.

Comment: @Al2110 yes... when user deletes row(s) from GridView by pressing `Delete` key, corresponding row(s) also will be deleted from the DataTable which is bound to the GridView.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I think there is a little confusion here. I have configured the `DataGridView` to be uneditable from the user's point of view. So, the only way to delete a row from the table is programmatically. I have tried to achieve this by adding a separate "delete" `Button`, whose click event handler has the code above. Clicking the button throws a "collection was modified; enumeration might not execute". I want to  be able to remove the selected row from the `DataTable`, then re-bind it to the `DataGridView`.

Comment: I have a possible solution for your problem... before that can you explain how are you binding the DataGridView to DataTable? Is the DataTable created at Form level? Also can you also mention the fact that the DataGridView in your situation is uneditable by the user?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I will add those to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... The dataGridView allows one row to be selected at a time ... which should delete the selected rows, by one of the columns ...

The [DataGridView.SelectedRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=net-5.0) property requires the [DataGridView.SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode?view=net-5.0) is set to `FullRowSelect` or `RowHeaderSelect` to return the selected rows. The entire row should be selected, not just some cells like in `RowHeaderSelect` option. Read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=net-5.0#remarks) section of the property.

In this case, you can delete a selected row like so:

```cs
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0 && !myGridView.SelectedRows[0].IsNewRow))
    {
        myGridView.Rows.Remove(myGridView.SelectedRows[0]);

        // Don't call this if you have a DB to update.
        // (myGridView.DataSource as DataTable).AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Or, if you have the `DataGridView.MultiSelect` property enabled:

```cs
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var r in myGridView.SelectedRows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(r => !r.IsNewRow))
            myGridView.Rows.Remove(r);

        // Don't call this if you have a DB to update.
        // (myGridView.DataSource as DataTable).AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Now, if you have the `SelectionMode` property set to one of the other values, then you can't count on the `SelectedRows` property. You need to get the selected rows through the [DataGridView.SelectedCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells?view=net-5.0) which is always populated regardless of the `SelectionMode` property value. [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells?view=net-5.0#remarks)

```cs
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var selRows = myGridView.SelectedCells
        .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
        .Where(c => !c.OwningRow.IsNewRow)
        .Select(c => c.OwningRow)
        .Distinct();

    foreach (var r in selRows)
        myGridView.Rows.Remove(r);

     // Don't call this if you have a DB to update.
     // (myGridView.DataSource as DataTable).AcceptChanges();
}
```

Or, get the [DataRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-5.0) objects from the selected rows through the [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=net-5.0) property and remove them from the `DataTable`.

```cs
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = myGridView.DataSource as DataTable;

    var selRows = myGridView.SelectedCells
        .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
        .Where(c => !c.OwningRow.IsNewRow)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(c => ((DataRowView)c.OwningRow.DataBoundItem).Row);

    foreach (var r in selRows)
        dt.Rows.Remove(r);

    // Don't call this if you have a DB to update.
    // dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

**Important**

As @Jimi commented, if you have a database in your project, then the [DataTable.AcceptChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges?view=net-5.0) method should only be called right after:

1. Populating the `DataTable`, loading the data from the database.
2. Commiting the changes, updating the database.

Comment: Yep, it's also important because you (the User) may want to roll-back the changes made. If you call `AcceptChanges()` the `DataTable.RejectChanges()` method won't help to get back the Rows you (marked as) deleted, in case you made a mistake and want them back, since all Rows will be marked as `Unchanged` (`DataRowState.Unchanged`) and `[DataTable].GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)?.Rows` will return an empty collection, so you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is modifying collections during enumeration.  Specifically both `foreach` loops.

You can get around this by marking things for deletion and then doing the actual deletes *after* you're done enumerating.

```
var rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow selected in myGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    string name = (string)selectedRow.Cells[0].Value;
    foreach (DataRow tableRow in usersTable.Rows)
    {
        if (tableRow["Name"].ToString().Equals(name))
            rowsToDelete.Add(tableRow);
    }
}
foreach (var row in rowsToDelete)
    row.Delete();
```

You could use `for` loops instead (this is not enumeration).  But then you have to track index changes so I prefer this method.

This requires few code changes.  You can simply delete rows directly from the grid, not the data source.

Regardless of method, you still need to avoid modifying the collection during enumeration with `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are trying to delete  the row while iterating thru the collection of rows which is causing the collection to be modified. That's why you are getting this error.

You need a way to delete the row from DataTable directly without iterating thru the Rows collection.

DataTable.Rows collection has `Remove` method which takes an instance of `DataRow` as a parameter.

So if you can get hold of the DataRow to be deleted, then all you need to do is call `usersTable.Rows.Remove` method.

As you can get hold of the original DataSource of GridView by doing

```
var usersTable = myGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
```

You can get hold of the individual DataItem bound to individual rows of DataGridView. Here in this case DataItem which is bound to rows of DataGridView will be `DataRowView`.

```
DataRowView rowView = selectedRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
```

And DataRowView has a property `Row` which represents the `DataRow` from the table which is bound to the GridVeiw. So you can use `rowView.Row` to call `Remove` method on `usersTable.Rows.Remove` method.

So the code of `delete_Click` can be changed to following to solve your issue.

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow selectedRow in myGridView.SelectedRows)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = selectedRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;

        if(rowView != null && rowView.Row != null)
        {
            // Removing row from the table created at the Form level.
            usersTable.Rows.Remove(rowView.Row);
        }
    }

    myGridView.Refresh();
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue.

P.S. : This solution is applicable only when you have DataTable used as DataSource of GridView. For any other type of DataSource a different solution may be needed.

Comment: After trying this, it throws "The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection".

Comment: Which line in the code throws the error? Are you using the same code as I have shared?