# How to remove a row from a connected MariaDB in DataGridView C# form using a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, mariadb

So basically I've got my MariaDB database connected to my DataGridView via connection string and I've successfully made an "Add row" button using textboxes as a reference for each column. My question is how can I delete a selected row from the DataGridView and the database itself using another button?

Looked everywhere online for a solution but most of them used the reverse of the "Add row" function (they delete based on values of each column, for an example when they type in "John" in the text box, the row where the "John" cell is gets deleted) or a DataGridView.CellClick event.

Comment: Is the button outside the DGV? Also I did a search with this lot of post delete row from datagridview using button in c#

Comment: No, the button is inside the DGV of course. It's basically a winform with DGV that's connected to my database, a few textboxes and 2 buttons (one for adding stuff that's written in the textbox to the database and other for deleting a selected row from DGV).

Comment: have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877420/deleting-selected-row-from-datatable-bound-datagridview and this is far out not sure it will help https://codepal.ai/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me. The method at the end is just my refresh data grid method when I add/remove rows.

```
private void btnUkloniStavku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MariaDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    if (drvniSortimentGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection konekcija = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            konekcija.Open();
            int odabraniIndex = drvniSortimentGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            int redID = int.Parse(drvniSortimentGridView[0, odabraniIndex].Value.ToString());
            string upit = "DELETE FROM drvnisortiment WHERE sortimentID=@SortimentID";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(upit, konekcija))
            {
                MySqlParameter RowParameter = new MySqlParameter();
                RowParameter.ParameterName = "@SortimentID";
                RowParameter.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
                RowParameter.IsNullable = false;
                RowParameter.Value = redID;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(RowParameter);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    OsvjeziGrid();
}
```